# Why i can connect to a sharepoint site with vba from one spreadsheet but not another

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint

I have an odd issue where I can connect and upload files to a sharepoint site using a vba script, however using practically the same vba script from another spreadsheet and uploading to the same sharepoint site I can't connect and upload files.

The weird thing with the vba script that doesn't work is that if I add the below code to it before the rest of the script, the rest of the script works.

```
 xPath= "https://teamspace.healthcare.siemens.com/content/90002613/Documents/"
 With ActiveWorkbook

    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & Name & ".xlsm"
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False

 End With
```

No idea why but xPath is a valid file path when using the SaveAs command, but when I use the same path or variant of it with the "Dir" tag it doesn't work and either give me a error code "Runtime 52 Bad File name or number" or "Runtime 76 path not found". Please can someone help with this, I have been trying everything I can think of for about the last 2 days

Thanks

Edit :

this is the code that works in one of the spreadsheets

```
If Dir("//teamspace.healthcare.siemens.com/content/90002613/Documents/GB_Invivo_RSM/" & xWs.Name & "", vbDirectory) = "" Then

            MkDir ("//teamspace.healthcare.siemens.com/content/90002613/Documents/GB_Invivo_RSM/" & xWs.Name & "")

            Else

            End If

  With ActiveWorkbook

Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "\GB_RSM_P" & Format(LDate, "mm") & "FY" & Format(LDate, "yyyy") & " " & xWs.Name & ".xlsx"
           End With
```

The code in the 2nd spreadsheet wont work unless I put another SaveAs() before all of this, and save a dummy spreadsheet, then have to delete it after, because obviously I don't want it there. I can't understand why the same code would work from one spreadsheet and not another, and also its almost like the saveAs() is creating a connection or something, but this wasn't needed in the 1st spreadsheet

Comment: Have you defined the name anywhere else in the code, it is possible that you are missing that part.

Comment: There should be a WebDAV path which may support use of `Dir`: you can't use a HTTP path for that.

Comment: Hi Thom, I have defined Name earlier in the code

Answer (score 0):

If your URL is "https://teamspace.healthcare.siemens.com/content/90002613/Documents/" then you should be able to use Dir() as shown below:

```
Sub TestWebDAVDir()

    Const MY_PATH As String = "\\teamspace.healthcare.siemens.com\content\90002613\Documents\"

    Dim f
    f = Dir(MY_PATH & "*")
    Do While Len(f) > 0
        Debug.Print f
        f = Dir()
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi All, the issue isn't actually to get the Dir() to work, because I already have the code working in a different spreadsheet, and have basically copied over to another spreadsheet and it doesn't work. Unless I use the saveas before the code, is there anything else you would need to do to get the Dir() to work?

Comment: I have edited my question to hopefully make more sense